# Laravel 4 pivot (many to many) table - when do I use ->get() and ::with()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I not getting any results from my many to many relationship when using ->get(). I am testing my relationship with the following:

The first part works. I am getting all the nests that have test@email.com in the pivot table. However I am bringing results back from a specific user ID. I do not want to do that.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
  foreach(User::find(2)->nest()->where('inviteEmail', '=', 'test@email.com')->get() as $nest)
    echo $nest->name, ': ', $nest->pivot->inviteEmail, "</br>";
});
```

I want to get all the nests which are associated to the email. I thought this would work:

```
foreach(User::with('nest')->where('inviteEmail', '=', 'test@email.com')->get() as $nest)
  echo $nest->name, ': ', $nest->pivot->inviteEmail, "</br>";
});
```

But I am getting this:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'inviteEmail' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `inviteEmail` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'test@email.com', ))

If I drop the `->get()` then I get a blank screen. Any ideas?

Comment: well, your error message states that you do not have an inviteEmail column in your users table.

Comment: I have the inviteEmil column in the pivot table. The first example above is evidence of that since I was able to get the value from that column. It looks like once I add the 'with' it is no longer looking in the pivot table.

Comment: I couldn't really get your database structure, could you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

To get all nests with `email` = `test@email.com`, make use of Eager Loading Constraints. Assuming you do have a `Nest` class, that's how you should do it:

```
$nests = Nest::with(array('user' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('nests_users.email', '=', 'test@email.com');
}));
```

You can read more on this on the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: How would this work with a pivot table? Not able to have this work with a many to many relationship.

Comment: Not really getting your point here. Would be easier if we could see how is your database structured.

Comment: I posted a more detailed post with my schema here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048086/laravel-4-pivot-table-many-to-many-not-loading