# Laravel 4 Pivot Table (many to many) not loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 tables: 'users' and 'nests' and 1 pivot table: 'nest_user'. In my pivot table I have email addresses I want to filter against so I can grab all the nests which have the associated email addreses. Here is my scehma:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->text('bio');
        $table->string('picture');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('visits');
        $table->integer('nest_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('nests', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('info');
        $table->integer('note_id');
        $table->integer('website_id');
        $table->integer('image_id');
        $table->integer('video_id');
        $table->integer('location_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('share_id');
        $table->string('inviteAuth');
        $table->string('tid');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('nest_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('nest_id');
        $table->string('inviteEmail');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I can do this no problem based on the User ID like this:

```
Route::get('/t1', function () {

    $nest = User::find(2)->nest()->where('inviteEmail', '=', 'martinelli@gmail.com')->get();

    foreach( $nest as $nest)

    echo $nest->name, ': ', $nest->pivot->inviteEmail, "</br>";
});
```

I can get the nest and name and the email in the pivot - awesome...However, I want to find ALL the 'nests' which have the associated email which is NOT tied to a user ID. This is getting me closer but it is still not working:

```
    Route::get('/t4', function () {

    $users = User::all();

    foreach($users as $users)
    {
        $nests = $users->with(array('nest' => function($query) {
        $query->where('inviteEmail', '=', 'martinelli@gmail.com');
    }))->get();

        foreach($nests->nest as $nest)
        {
            echo $nest->name,"<br />";

        }
    }

    });
```

I am getting this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$nest
```

Comment: I hope someone can help. This is the last big logic/syntax hurdle I have with Laravel. I have tried every configuration based on the docs and I am still not successful. Any insight would be great. I feel I am so close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but your last code block doesn't make sense. You'll want to do the with while fetching the users. Also, the error you're getting makes sense, because the $nests (Collection) doesn't have a $nest property.

Again, I'm not sure this is what you're after, but give this a try:

```
Route::get('/t4', function () {

    // Get all users and their nests where nests are filtered by inviteEmail
    $users = User::with(array('nest' => function($query) {
        $query->where('inviteEmail', '=', 'martinelli@gmail.com');
    }))->get();

    // Loop through all users
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        // I'm asuming you defined the relation as nests() in your User model.
        foreach($user->nests as $nest)
        {
            echo $nest->name . "<br />";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...this did work but I am trying to access the pivot table column but this solution looks like it is accessing the nest table. I was able to refactor the logic a tad and got it to work with the nest table using your code. Thanks!